# animate scroll top перестал работать в Chrome в версии 61.x

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте, есть простая функция скролла вниз:

```
$('body').animate({ scrollTop: $('.addanswer').offset().top - 70 }, 500);
```

Но дело в том что вчера она внезапно перестала работать на хроме, хоть я и не вводил правки в код, причем в Яндекс браузере все корректно работает, не подскажите, это обновления такие?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот простой пример, и оно работает, дело не в скрипте а в самой странице, что то там не дает работать вашему коду. посмотрите ошибки в кансоле.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.scroll').bind('click',function(){
    $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $('div').offset().top - 70 }, 500);
  });
});
```

```css
div{
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<button class="scroll">scroll</button>
```

Comment: Вы уверены, что ваш пример работает?

Comment: @Cheg Если вы не уверены что не работает значит пример правильный )))

Comment: я-то как раз уверен, что в хроме он не работает

Comment: @Cheg тогда бы у меня сейчас не работало, я на хроме

Comment: @Cheg Могу и видео сделать что работает

Comment: Видимо что-то с хромом, потому что сейчас пытаюсь воспроизвести ваш код - не работает, версия хрома - 61.0.3163.100 опять таки в Яндекс браузере все норм

Comment: @Владимир У меня версия `Версия 59.0.3071.115 (Официальная сборка), (64 бит)` можете проверить на этой

Comment: Я понимаю что там будет работать, остается вопрос, это баг или фишка новой версии

Comment: @Владимир, Версия 61.0.3163.100 (Официальная сборка), (64 бит)
Не работает. Дело в хроме.

Comment: @Владимир я поменял ответ, и сейчас оно должно работать

Comment: да действительно работает, видимо на body скролл уже не будет работать, нужно юзать ваш пример

Comment: @Владимир Я не сделал тест без `body` на разных браузерах и версиях, но сейчас если оставить обе то оно не чему мешать не будет.

Comment: @Cheg посмотрите обновленный ответ.

Comment: @VasiliyRusin Уже работает.

Comment: Ну наконец-то... А вот видео так я и не дождался...

Comment: @Cheg Когда автор сказал уже про версию, вот и ответ изменился, а до версии 61 и без изменения работает.